# Excel VBA return a cell value from a range defined thru application.inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

The user would select a range thru the `Application.InputBox` method. Then I would like to check the value in the very first cell in that range.

The following code produces an error. Any help, please?

```
Sub User_Range_Selection()
Dim xRg As Range

Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range:", "Range Selection", , , , , , 8)

MsgBox xRn.Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1MS8.gif).

Your last code line before exiting the sub procedure changes `xRg` to `xRn`. This would have been caught with Option Explicit.

```
Option Explicit

Sub User_Range_Selection()

    Dim xRg As Range

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range:", "Range Selection", type:=8)

    MsgBox xRg.Cells(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add an error handling, to prevent user input but closing form halting your code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Do
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range:", "Range Selection", , , , , , 8)
Loop While xRg Is Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox xRg.Cells(1, 1).Value
```